# How to get the name of a country or a city or a state with Nokia Maps?

Tags: javascript, geocode, here-api

I'm developing with Nokia Maps (a wonderful option I really love them) but I'm only able to get the location (latitude and longitude) with HTML5 but I can't the name where I am :/, maybe somebody could give an idea, how to do it, thank you very mach for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Maps API for JavaScript 3.x**

The current 3.x JavaScript API offers a thin wrapper around the REST [Geocoder API](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder). You need to make a **ReverseGeocode** search, and then extract the data from the [**Location**](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html#address) object(s) found in the result.

A fully working reverse geocoding example can be found [here](http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#maps-js/reverse-geocode-an-address-from-location), but the important bit (getting the address) can be see below:

```
    function reverseGeocode(platform) {
  var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService(),
    reverseGeocodingParameters = {
      prox: '52.5309,13.3847,150', // Location
      mode: 'retrieveAddresses',
      maxresults: '1',
      jsonattributes : 1
    };

  geocoder.reverseGeocode(
    reverseGeocodingParameters,
    function (result) {
      var locations = result.response.view[0].result;
      // ... etc.
    },
    function (error) {
      alert('Ooops!');
    }
  );
}
```

**Maps API for JavaScript 2.x (deprecated)**

With the recently **deprecated** 2.x JavaScript API, again you need to make a **ReverseGeocode** search, and then extract the data from the [**Address**](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.places.objects.Place.location.address.html) object found in the result.

The code is a bit longer, but the important bit (getting the address) can be seen below:

```
// Function for receiving search results from places search and process them
var processResults = function (data, requestStatus, requestId) {
    var i, len, locations, marker;

    if (requestStatus == "OK") {
        // The function findPlaces() and reverseGeoCode() of  return results in slightly different formats
        locations = data.results ? data.results.items : [data.location];
        // We check that at least one location has been found
        if (locations.length > 0) {

            for (i = 0, len = locations.length; i < len; i++) {
                alert(locations[i].address.street);
                alert(locations[i].address.state);
            }

        } else { 
            alert("Your search produced no results!");
        }
    } else {
        alert("The search request failed");
    }
};



/* We perform a reverse geocode search request: translating a given 
 * latitude & longitude into an address
 */
var reverseGeoCodeTerm = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(
    52.53099,
    13.38455
);



nokia.places.search.manager.reverseGeoCode({
    latitude: reverseGeoCodeTerm.latitude,
    longitude: reverseGeoCodeTerm.longitude,
    onComplete: processResults
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for the late replay :/